# How to selectively enable and disable scroll button based on window size

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I am trying to make a scroll viewer in which scroll button is visible only when window size is too small to show all the content. I have put some button into a stackpanel which is in the scrollviewer.

```
<Grid>
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>

            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RepeatButton x:Name="LineLeftButton" 
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="0"

                Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineDownCommand}" 
                Background="{StaticResource uparrow}"
                CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer}"/>
        <RepeatButton x:Name="LineRightButton" 
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="2"
              Background="{StaticResource downarrow}" 
                Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}"      
                CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer}"/>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="scrollViewer" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button Width="150" Height="20"/>
            <Button Width="150" Height="20"/>
            <Button Width="150" Height="20"/>
            <Button Width="150" Height="20"/>
            <Button Width="150" Height="20"/>
            <Button Width="150" Height="20"/>

            <Button Width="150" Height="20"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

The scroll is working kk but how do you disable it when there are not enough element in the stack such that a scroll is not required?

Comment: i dont want the scroll bar. i just need the scroll button to be visible when its required

Comment: sorry i misunderstood

Comment: thats alright , dou have ant suggestion how i can hide the repeat button in my code based on requirement

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a converter like the following

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {
            return ((double)value < 140) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

where 140 is the total height needed (you can make this parameter dynamic). Then you just need to bind the visibility of your button

```
<RepeatButton x:Name="LineRightButton" 
                Visibility="{Binding ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource MyConv}, ElementName=scrollViewer, Mode=OneWay}"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Background="{StaticResource downarrow}" 
                Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}"      
                CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer}"/>
```

You just need to define the converter mentioned above in your resources and it's done

**EDIT** Solution number 2 with Multibinding:

if you want to avoid to hardcode the total height of your button you can use a multivalueconverter and a multibinding

```
public class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value[0] is double && value[1] is double)
        {
            return ((double)value[0] < (double)value[1]) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }


    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and modify your button in this way

```
<RepeatButton x:Name="LineRightButton" 
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="2"
          Background="Black" 
            Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}"      
            CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer}">
        <RepeatButton.Visibility>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConv}">
                <Binding Path="ActualHeight"  ElementName="scrollViewer"/>
                <Binding Path="ActualHeight"  ElementName="test"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </RepeatButton.Visibility>
    </RepeatButton>
```

where "test is the name of the stackpanel containing the buttons

Comment: Yes. I did it just for one button to let you understand my solution. You have to apply the same code also to the other button

Comment: i messed up while giving the position of the buttons , its working now

Comment: do have any suggestion on how to get scroll function when mouse is over the repeat button.

Comment: @jithin you need an event trigger probably. However sonce it is another question, and this one is solved, i suggest you to ask another question here on SO

Comment: i did this .Please look into it.
the url is
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47747417/how-to-get-scroll-function-in-a-repeat-button-when-mouse-is-over-the-button

Comment: how should i modify the ur converter to hide the repeat button(up scroll)when there  top most button in stack is selected

Comment: my converter is only for what you have requested, i.e. hide/show repeat buttons based on how many space you have. To do other visual thing you have either to add triggers probably. With selected are you meaning clicked?