# How to get scroll function in a repeat button when mouse is over the button

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a repeat button that scrolls the contents of the scroll viewer. I want to scroll when the mouse is hovered or clicked on the button.

```
<RepeatButton x:Name="down" 
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
          Background="{StaticResource uparrow}" 
            Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineDownCommand}"      
            CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer}">
            <RepeatButton.Visibility >
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
                    <Binding Path="ActualHeight"  ElementName="scrollViewer"/>
                    <Binding Path="ActualHeight"  ElementName="test"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </RepeatButton.Visibility>
        </RepeatButton>
        <RepeatButton x:Name="up" 
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="2"
          Background="{StaticResource downarrow}" 

            Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}"      
            CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer}">
            <RepeatButton.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
                    <Binding Path="ActualHeight"  ElementName="scrollViewer"/>
                    <Binding Path="ActualHeight"  ElementName="test"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </RepeatButton.Visibility>
        </RepeatButton>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="scrollViewer" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <StackPanel x:Name="test"  Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button Width="150" Height="20"/>
            <Button Width="150" Height="20"/>
            <Button Width="150" Height="20"/>
            <Button Width="150" Height="20"/>
            <Button Width="150" Height="20"/>
            <Button Width="150" Height="20"/>

            <Button Width="150" Height="20"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

The code works when i click on the button. But i have no idea how to enable scrolling when mouse is hovered over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed this by adding PreviewMouseWheel event of the repeat button.
The code behind is

```
 private void up_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Delta < 0)
            {
                scrollViewer.LineDown();
            }
            else
            {
                scrollViewer.LineUp();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` Events on your button to achieve your goal. Following code snippet might help you:

```
       private void Mouse_Enter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
       {
           int max = txtbox1.Text.Length;
           for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
           {
               txtbox1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(i);
               //add some delay to see the scrolling effect
           }
       }

      private void Mouse_Leave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
      {
          return;
      }
```

Comment: i actually want to control a stackpanel placed inside a scroll viewer. when mouse is over this button, scroll on mouse should work.thats what i am trying to implement

Comment: I have used a text box in the above example. You can use the same example for a `ScrollPanel`. Just replace the term txtbox1 with your ScrollPanel's name.

Comment: that i understood , but this not what i am trying to implement.i suppose i wasnt clear on what i was trying do what i am trying to do is when mouse is over the button i want to use the scroll wheel of mouse to scroll the stackpanel

Comment: So you want to enable scrolling *only* when the mouse is hovered over the button?
In that case you can use a while statement to check if mouse is on the button and then disable scrolling by using 

`stackpanel.SetValue(ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled); `

Comment: i want scrolling when mouse is hovered over the button which in not in the stack panel and when mouse is in the stack panel

Comment: i wrote a mouseover event for the button that needs to control the scroll of the stackpanel. the code is
 private void mousewheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            ScrollViewer scrollviewer1 = sender as ScrollViewer;
            if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                scrollviewer1.LineUp();
            }
            else
            {
                scrollviewer1.LineDown();
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
but this hits a null point exception